# Why didn't The Mountain enforce Cersei's order?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S07E07 "The Dragon and the Wolf" of *Game of Thrones*, while Jaime is preparing his troops to march to Winterfell, Cersei pulls him aside & tells him she means to double cross the rest. She has no intention of helping Dany & Jon.

Jaime says he made a promise to fight for the living & he intends to keep it & abandons Cersei. She calls it treason & nods to The Mountain to kill Jaime. He draws his sword & blocks Jaime's way.

Jaime calls out this bluff & walks away from her & The Mountain doesn't do anything. How did Mountain interpret Cersei intentions really. Cersei doesn't nod again for him to stop. He's supposed to be an undead mute.

Why didn't The Mountain enforce Cersei's order to kill Jaime?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the already answered question. The actual answer seems to be the last one by @TheLethalCarrot where it is stated there are 2 nods. One to draw & one to swing.

Comment: That's why it is the one with bounty ;)